# What is the correct code to find identify dupe rows and merge them together?

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL data pull that currently has dupe rows per product. In these dupe rows, some of the PKs per product are the same but what's different is the discount. The discounts will be different per product. For eg. Product A is listed twice on the pull but has a varying discount of .10 vs .15 for example:

[image: 1]

I want to be able to merge both rows into one row and make it look like this:
[image: 2]

What does the code look like for that

Comment: It's totally unclear how you would determine the two different types of discounts in the information you've given.

Comment: Well you can't have duplicate primary keys, so what do you mean by dupe rows? If this is duplicate data on insertion, you can simply have it ignore dupe errors and continue on during an import.

Comment: @stdunbar The lowest discount would be for the regular customers and the highest for the vip customers

Comment: @Phaelaxz on the data pull itself product is showing up twice and sometimes even three times. Again, the only thing different is the discounts per product.

Comment: Do you have control over the pull query? Or are you able to put the data into a temp table?

Comment: I am able to pull the data into a temp table, I've tried doing that but I am having issues coming up with the write code to write in it @Phaelaxz

Comment: How will you determine which row is regular and which is vip?

Comment: @Phaelaxz the lowest discount will be for regular and the highest discount will be vip

Answer (score 0):

This assumes PK will only have 2 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INTEGER ,
  discount int
);


INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (0001, 20);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (0001, 10);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (0045, 15);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (0045, 35);


SELECT id, substring_index(dl, ',', 1) as `regular`, substring_index(dl, ',', -1) as `vip`
FROM (
  SELECT id, group_concat(discount order by discount) dl
  FROM table1 GROUP BY id
) t
```